# ¿Se puede agregar un campo en base de datos que se inicialice con el valor de otros campos automáticamente?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo en una tabla 2 columnas o campos: **A** y **B**.

Ejemplo: **A = 44** y **B = 123**

¿Se puede agregar una nueva columna en base de datos que se inicialice con un valor compuesto por estos valores automáticamente?

Ejemplo: nueva columna "Compuesto", valor: **0044000123**

¿Se puede (a nivel base de datos - SQL) inicializar los **valores ya existentes** en la tabla **y los futuros valores** de los registros que se agreguen?

Ejemplo: si yo agrego nuevo registro con **A=55** y **B=456**, que la nueva columna tome el valor **0055000456**.

Para no tener que realizar esta tarea por software.

Comment: Si, con un trigger, pero no deberias hacerlo en la mayoria de los casos.. estas penalizando los insert y updates para arreglar algo de otro lado. Con un ejemplo no trivial como el que mostras podriamos decirte si seria correcto o no...

Comment: Creo que lo primero sería poner el motor de base de datos que usas, ya que no puede ser `mysql`,`postgresql` y `oracle` a la vez. Cada motor tiene sus propias particularidades y sus propias posibilidades. Además tener la definición de las tablas sería, cuanto menos, interesante. Puede serte de interés leer [ask].

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi El ejemplo es genérico porque la consulta es a nivel general. A nivel software pueden haber 100 programas haciendo inserts en la tabla y es costoso identificarlos, actualizarlos y testearlos todos. Perfecto! busco como hacerlo con un trigger.

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2. La consulta es a nivel general, independientemente de la tabla y a nivel SQL (puede ser para esos motores e incluso más, como SQL Server). Quito motores particulares de las etiquetas entonces, gracias por responder.

Comment: cada vez la embarras mas.. si es como decis, muchos programas haciendo insert a la tabla, entonces menos que menos es un trigger.. es NADA y que lo solucione el que lee los datos.. por eso, a veces las preguntas genericas generan mas problemas de los que solucionan...

Comment: Una respuesta genérica para una pregunta genérica: *¿Se puede agregar un campo en base de datos que se inicialice con el valor de otros campos automáticamente?*. **Sí. Se puede**. Espero te haya sido de utilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que la respuesta depende del motor de Base de Datos.
Por ejemplo en MySQL se puede aprovechar el uso de los valores por default al generar columnas en las tablas (algunas otras bases de datos permiten también generar operaciones de este estilo).

Te comparto una forma de hacer lo que mencionas sin incluir triggers.
Coméntame por favor si te es de utilidad lo que te comparto.

[image: Agregando columna con valores por default]

Comment: Es de perfecta utilidad @alvaro-c ! Genera el dato en nuevos inserts y también lo hace para registros que existían anteriormente. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.